# Why isn't combineReducers receiving state in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

When I look at a reducer being called via `combineReducers`, it's not getting the state or action in the arguments.

My reducers file is this:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import nav from './reducers/nav';
import pages from './reducers/pages';
import entities from './reducers/entities';

export default function(initialData) {

  return function(state, action) {
    if (!state) {
      console.log('no state', initialData);
      return initialData;
    }

    // This is showing state as having expected value
    console.log('state', state);

    return combineReducers({
      nav,
      pages,
      entities
    });
  }
};
```

My store initialization is like this:

```
import reducerWrapper from './reducers';

// Initial state is defined above
var reducers = reducerWrapper(initialState),
    store = Redux.createStore(reducers, initialState);
```

The [example code on the site](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) doesn't use a wrapper (which I had seen in some other example). I tried that too and it didn't work. I mean in either example I'm not sure how it would get state/action given what is written out. I feel like I'm missing some magic here.

**Updated**
Here is the reducers file now:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import nav from './reducers/nav';
import pages from './reducers/pages';
import entities from './reducers/entities';

export default combineReducers({
  nav,
  pages,
  entities
});
```

followed by `store = Redux.createStore(reducerWrapper, initialState)`, also doesn't work, even when I remove the wrapping inside `reducerWrapper` and just export default combineReducers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer wasn't easily seen here. The problem is that my reducer did not have a default state.

The store triggers an INIT event here: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L204

It then eventually gets to here:
https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/combineReducers.js#L52

Meaning if my reducer is `function (state, action) { return state }` rather than `function (state='anyDefaultValue') { return state }`, `combineReducer` will error saying that the reducer did not return state

Answer (score 0):

`combineReducers` returns a function that needs to be invoked with `state` and `action`. You can just export that directly:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers(...);
export default rootReducer;
```

Or you can wrap it as you currently are:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers(...);
export default function (initialData) {
  return function (state, action) {
    if (!state) {
      console.log('no state', initialData);
      return initialData;
    }

    // This is showing state as having expected value
    console.log('state', state);

    return rootReducer(state, action);
  }
}
```